# Effective way to iterate and calculate based on dates and ID conditions in large dataset using Pyspark/Databricks

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I don't have experience in Pyspark, so if anyone could help me with the following issue:

I have the following Spark dataframe:

```
| ID_user | date_contract | total_debt | 
| 2564541 | 2015-08-22    |64          | 
| 2564541 | 2019-05-16    |100         |
| 2564541 | 2020-08-15    |200         |
| 2564541 | 2021-09-17    |150         |
| 3000000 | 2014-08-22    |84          |
| 3000000 | 2015-08-23    |100         |
| 3000000 | 2016-08-24    |200         |
```

As you can see above, there are users with more than one contract and they can do just one contract per day. So the goal is to calculate total debt average, for each user (`ID_user`), of all contracts agreed before the current contract.

So the user `2564541` did a contract on `2021-09-17`, so the average debt based on all contracts agreed for him before that contract (in 2020/2019/2015) is `mean(200,100,64) = 121,33`.

I think some kind of iteration is needed because I have to do the same for each `id_user` and for each date of contract.

Expected output:

```
| ID_user | date_contract | total_debt | avg_debt_before |
| 2564541 | 2015-08-22    |64          | 0               |
| 2564541 | 2019-05-16    |100         | 64              |
| 2564541 | 2020-08-15    |200         | 82              |
| 2564541 | 2021-09-17    |150         | 121,3           |
| 3000000 | 2014-08-22    |84          | 0               |
| 3000000 | 2015-08-23    |30          | 84              |
| 3000000 | 2016-08-24    |50          | 57              |
```

I've already tried using `rdd.toLocalIterator()`, but no success. I've spent almost all week searching for an answer here too, so any help or tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a rolling average. You can calculate it using `avg` function over a Window partitioned by `ID_user` and ordered by `date_contract`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = (Window.partitionBy("ID_user")
     .orderBy("date_contract")
     .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
     )

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "avg_debt_before",
    F.round(F.coalesce(F.avg("total_debt").over(w), F.lit(0)), 2)
)

df1.show()
#+-------+-------------+----------+---------------+
#|ID_user|date_contract|total_debt|avg_debt_before|
#+-------+-------------+----------+---------------+
#|2564541|   2015-08-22|        64|            0.0|
#|2564541|   2019-05-16|       100|           64.0|
#|2564541|   2020-08-15|       200|           82.0|
#|2564541|   2021-09-17|       150|         121.33|
#|3000000|   2014-08-22|        84|            0.0|
#|3000000|   2015-08-23|       100|           84.0|
#|3000000|   2016-08-24|       200|           92.0|
#+-------+-------------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was expecting for. Just one question: I had a lot a of problems using some functions with this big dataset, even high order functions. Have you used coalesce to reduce the paralelism of Spark? I've searched that function and that it was I understood.